# Mysql Php, queries are very slow

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, view

I have an application hosted on sandbox.promls.net

There are some issues with the queries that I'm using for retrieve information to my server I'm still on development phase so there is not much data loaded into the database.

This is the query I'm executing (it's a view):

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id , name, contact, email_contact, phone_contact, address, phone, fax, email, website, creation_date, last_modification, zipcode, longitude, latitude, gmtoffset, dstoffset, area_id, area, status , logo, type, owner_id, users, created_by, created_by_id 
    from companies_listing 
    limit 0,15
```

It takes 19.6522991657 seconds to execute. Help me please!

the structure of view is the following:

the view structure is the following:

```
 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `companies_listing`;
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `companies_listing` AS
  select `c`.`id` AS `id`, `c`.`name` AS `name`,`c`.`contact` AS `contact`,
    `c`.`phone_contact` AS `phone_contact`,`c`.`email_contact` AS `email_contact`,
    `c`.`address` AS `address`,`c`.`phone` AS `phone`,`c`.`fax` AS `fax`,
    `c`.`owner_id` AS `owner_id`,`c`.`email` AS `email`,
    `c`.`website` AS `website`,`c`.`creation_date` AS `creation_date`,
    `c`.`last_modification` AS `last_modification`,`c`.`zipcode` AS `zipcode`,
    `c`.`type` AS `type`,`c`.`status` AS `status`,`a`.`description` AS `area`,
    `c`.`area_id` AS `area_id`,`c`.`logo` AS `logo`,
    `c`.`created_by` AS `creator_id`,`u`.`fullname` AS `creator`,
    (select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `users` `uu` 
       where (`uu`.`company_id` = `c`.`id`)
    ) AS `users` 
    from (
       (`company` `c` 
       join `areas` `a` 
        on((`a`.`id` = `c`.`area_id`))
       )
       join `users` `u` on((`u`.`id` = `c`.`created_by`))
    );

Query explain select id , name, contact, email_contact, phone_contact, address,
                phone, fax, email, website, creation_date, last_modification, 
                area_id, area, status , logo, type, owner_id, users, creator,
                creator_id
                from companies_listing, Thu Feb 10 17:45:37 2011

id   select_type             table       type     possible_keys  key    key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY                 <derived2>  ALL       10             (null)
2   DERIVED                 c           ALL       FK_company_1_company              18  (null)
2   DERIVED                 u           eq_ref      PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   inmobili.c.created_by   1   (null)
2   DERIVED                 a           eq_ref      PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   inmobili.c.area_id  1   (null)
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY      uu          ref fk_user_company fk_user_company 4   inmobili.c.id   1   Using index
```

Comment: Well, could you post the view definition, and its execution plan? (run with `EXPLAIN SELECT` instead of just `SELECT`) It's impossible to tell anything with the amount of data you gave us so far.

Comment: Wow. What's the `EXPLAIN` look like? (Just prepend "explain" to the select statement, in phpMyAdmin if you have it available.)

Comment: Could you include some idea of the table structure, as well as the number of rows total in the table?  There are hundreds of reasons that a database query can go slowly, from poor schema design, poor or absent use of indexes, to inadequate resources on the server.

Comment: That looks good to me. It sounds more like there is something else wrong. #1, and most likely, its probably the host, or #2, some other PHP code. Could you post the other PHP code?

Comment: @Oscar Godson: Except it's not an actual table, it's a view - there could be some horrible monster lurking behind this façade. (I once saw a similarly innocent view...that was selecting from other views, two levels deep, joins too terrible to mention, and crawling subqueries - but you'd never guess from the queries that only referenced the view, except for their otherwordly slowness, and a slight feeling of unease they were spreading, like dark, ominously curling tendrils of smoke...)

Comment: Hi to everyone, the database is on development enviroment so there are no many rows on the database, i'm using a dedicated server at theplanet and :

Comment: the view structure is the following:

Comment: by the way i'm usign views cause i prefer recude the use of memory instide of hard disk space. by the way i hear the view as created on the database and automatically saves the information on a existing table that hold the information for views. so views are more faster than execute a direct consult to the tables usign joins

Comment: @Angel Estrada: "views are faster" - that is an overgeneralization, it is definitely not true in every case (and MySQL doesn't materialize the views in a useful way, so you don't get that speed benefit anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is very slow all and all.. and that it's almost faster to just take and replicate the query without the limit than use mysql_num_rows to generate the amount of rows that exists.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: really...i was using it because was more flexibles, what about use store procedures instead views.

Answer (score 0):

- Those parentheses in your `FROM` clause aren't adding legibility, and they have impact on efficiency (as the main query becomes "derived" when it doesn't have to)
- you should make indexes on all the colums that you are joining/querying by (`` `c`.`area_id` `` and `` `c`.`created_by` `` are the obvious ones

Comment: it was created by phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Angel Estrada: ...and? I'm not trying to blame you, I'm pointing out possible areas for improvement. phpMyAdmin, AFAIK, doesn't try to optimize your query in any way - it will put it together, yes, but it won't try to be particularly efficient.

Comment: hi there, ok. sorry i didn't try to reflect that. by the way let me say you that my problem is solve, i really optimize my queries but there were others problems: i was using an excesive use of data encryptation which makes my script going very slow. i'm fixing it know. if you know one class that makes encryptations more fast. please let me know, thanks in advance and thanks agaen for you help let me told you that your comments were really helpfull